# get a >24 fps framerate in HTML5 video?

Tags: html, video, html5-video

So while the DOM, canvas and webgl can hit framerates of up to 60fps, video seems to be stuck at 24fps for the moment.

That framerate is more convention than anything I believe, both the codecs and video container formats don't have restrictions there (well, not all of them).

I'd love to see a `<video>` tag showing a clip at like 48 or 60fps. Is this possible, and if so, how can it best be done?

Comment: Not everyone has a connection fast enough to do this

Comment: see http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/movies/2011/03/james-cameron-champions-faster-film-projection-rates.html

Comment: Per Steve Lacey's answer, try a completely different browser.

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this problem with? If Chrome, pls file a bug at http://crbug.com

Comment: re: "That framerate is more convention than anything", it's one of the 3 main framerates used.  (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate#cite_note-Brownlow-1 ) and, apart from other advantages, it derives from the speed at which the early Edison silent films tried to record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the video is encoded at a high frame rate and the browser's media player implementation can keep up, then there's nothing stopping playback at a higher frame rate.

Comment: How do I know if my browser's media player implementation "can keep up" ?