# How many frames per second can we get on html5 video?

Tags: javascript, html, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get a >24 fps framerate in HTML5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089713/get-a-24-fps-framerate-in-html5-video)

And if it's not a matter of html5, what is it that determines how high a frame rate we can get? I asking because I'd like to film several things in 60fps and create a slow motion function in JavaScript.

Comment: That really depends on how long it takes to process a frame.  I'm relatively sure you would have no problem drawing a static image onto a canvas at 60fps (you can test that assumption easily enough.  It's something like 16ms / frame, probably close to the a given system's timer resolution, which is 15ms on Windows short of the high performance timer calls), but blit'ing to the screen is not usually the bottleneck.  You really don't give us enough information to even guess.

Comment: 0FPS on my Pentium 90. ;) The ``<video>`` tag uses a codec to decode the video, so it could use the GPU, or it might not. Then the video frames are put through the DOM renderer -- slower if you have stuff moving or overlaying on top of the video, etc. And each browser will have different performance characteristics. So I don't think this is an answerable question -- not in a precise sense, at least.

Comment: More than your eyes can assimilate

Comment: Haha, woah.  So Firefox is supposed to update the timeupdate event once per frame, so I wonder how it might do that.  If it depends on so much, I guess my next question would be, what happens if I upload a video that's 60fps, would it degrade gracefully on machines that can't handle 60fps?  Wow, sorry, didn't know this was that complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only depends on the encoded video (frame rate of actual video) and implementation of the browser vendor (whether media player in browser supports that much fps).

Comment: It it possible to find out which browsers support 60fps videos?

Comment: @Andrew I'm not aware of any. You can check browser support for html5 video in several ways (one of which is: http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5), I think that currently support will depend mainly on hardware.

Comment: Arman> There are quite a few sites that can say if your browser has support for HTML5 or not, but they don't say if my browser will be able to show 60fps video....

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've accidentally deleted some part of my comment while writing. I meant that you can check for html5 video support, but I don't think that you can check how much fps player will support. It depends on too many things, not only on browser support, but also on hardware, codec versions...

Comment: I wonder if anyone managed to get 60fps with their browser...i have tried several different PCs and a bunch of browsers but non of them seems to be able to run at 60fps...Any successful examples?